# how to debug a POST 500 internal server error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to set up jquery file upload on a Rails 3.2 app, following this [guide](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Rails-setup-for-V6).

Everything is almost working perfectly *but*, when I click "start upload" I see an error in Chrome's console:

```
POST http://testapp.dev/photos 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

In the log I'm getting:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template photos/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, :html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}.
```

I've been through the controller with a fine tooth comb, but I can't work out what is causing this error or why its looking for a create partial. What is a systematic way to debug this?

Thanks

*EDIT*

My controller actions look like this:

```
class PhotosController < ApplicationController

  def index

   @photos = Photo.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @photos }
      format.json { render :json => @photos.collect { |a| a.to_jq_upload }.to_json }
      format.js { render :json => @photos.collect { |a| a.to_jq_upload }.to_json }
    end
  end

  def show
    @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @photo }
      format.json { render :json => @photo }
      format.js   
    end
  end

  def new
    @photo = Photo.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @photo }
      format.json { render :json => @photo }
      format.js 
    end
  end


  def edit
    @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])

  end

  def create
    @photo = Photo.new(params[:photo])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @photo.save
        format.html {  
                  render :json => [@photo.to_jq_upload].to_json, 
                  :content_type => 'text/html',
                  :layout => false
                }
        format.json { render :json => [ @photo.to_jq_upload].to_json }
        format.js

      else 
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @photo.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render :json => [  {:error => "An error was encountered while processing your photos. Please try again."}], status: 304 }
        format.js
      end      
    end
  end



      def update
    @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @photo.update_attributes(params[:photo])
        format.html { redirect_to(@photo, :notice => 'Asset was successfully updated.') }
        format.xml  { head :ok }
        format.json { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @photo.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @photo.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /assets/1
  # DELETE /assets/1.xml
  def destroy
    @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
    @photo.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to(photos_url) }
      format.xml  { head :ok }
      format.json { render :json => true }
      format.js
    end
  end
    end
```

Comment: Anything in your application's log?

Comment: Did you check your app's logs? I don't know your type of production. On heroku it's `heroku logs` or `heroku logs -n 500` to retrieve 500 lines.

Comment: Yes, I'm getting `ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template photos/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, :html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}.`. Why is it looking for a create partial?

Comment: In the example the controller is named `PicturesController` but your URL is `photos`, that doesn't seem correct.

Comment: thanks @Stefan, my model is called Photo. I'm freestylin' :)

Comment: thanks @YuriBarbashov, I've added my controller actions to the questio

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like the `respond_to` block is hitting `format.js` which will attempt to render a template (a default if no options are provided).

Because the jQuery-file-upload plugin you're using requires a particular JSON response, having a `respond_to` block seems unnecessary and you can get away with the following

```
def create
    @photo = Photo.new(params[:photo])

    if @photo.save
        render :json => [ @photo.to_jq_upload].to_json
    else 
        render :json => [{ :error => "An error was encountered while processing your photos. Please try again." }], :status => 304
    end      
end
```

I would also highly recommend the [debugger](http://rubygems.org/gems/debugger) gem which will allow you to set breakpoints within the application so you can better tell what is happening.

To add the `debugger` gem, you'll need to first add the gem to your `Gemfile` and run a `bundle install` from the command line. Next, you simply add the word `debugger` on the line of code you want to set the breakpoint at. In your case, you could do

```
def create
    @photo = Photo.new(params[:photo])
    debugger

    if @photo.save
    # ... rest of code
```

Finally, you'll need to restart the server with the `--debugger` option. When the jQuery-file-upload plugin posts the request to the server, it'll hit the breakpoint and you can better analyze the passed params as well as step through the code to get an idea of what is happening. Cheers.

Comment: you sir are the man! +1 for the answer. If I could, +1 for giving me the tools to work this out myself. Thank you, I've been puzzling over this for days.